# A thickening map on integer partitions

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, partitions

I am looking for the name of the following map $t(\mu)$, defined for integer partitions $\mu=\mu_1\geq\mu_2\geq\dots$:

1. if $\mu$ is empty, return $\mu$.
2. if the first part $\mu_1$ of $\mu$ is at least the number of parts of $\mu$, return the partition $\mu_1, t(\mu_2,\dots)$
3. otherwise, let $\lambda=\mu^t$ and return $\lambda_1, t(\lambda_2,\dots)$.

One property of $t$ is that $t(\mu)$ dominates $\mu$, but I'm not sure whether this is the maps natural context.

Answer (score 2):

The partitions produced by the map are called [superdiagonal partitions](http://oeis.org/A238873) in OEIS, so absent a better reference you could call it the superdiagonalising map.

Comment: SSSSSSSSSSuper!

Comment: Or, depending on your British/American English preference, superdiagonalizing.